# got "tar: /path/to/my/dir: Not found in archive" error while verifying created archive

Tags: tar, compression, error-handling, archive, lzma

I did compress a directory to `.tar.xz` archive format with this command:

```
tar --create --verbose --file myArchive.tar.xz /path/to/my/dir
```

then,I tried to check health of created archive with following command:

```
tar --compare --file myArchive.tar.xz /path/to/my/dir
```

and I got this error lines :

```
tar: /path/to/my/dir: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with  failure status due to previous error
```

I retried it but got same resault.what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use absolute path names, then you should consider using `-P` for both your `--create` and `--compare` commands.

```
    -P, --absolute-names
        Don't strip leading slashes from file names when creating archives.
```

Example:

```
$ tar -cvPf a.tar /home/user/test_file
/home/user/test_file
$ tar -dvPf a.tar /home/user/test_file
/home/user/test_file
```

---

Or you could use `-C`, to change directory before the comparison.

```
    -C, --directory=DIR
        Change to DIR before performing any operations. This option is
        order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```

Example:

```
tar -cvf a.tar /home/user/test_file
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/user/test_file
tar -dvf a.tar -C/ home/user/test_file
home/user/test_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The leading `/` may have been removed, therefore the pathname cannot be found in the archive.

When using the standard GNU `tar` and adding files `/absolute/path/file.ext` the leading `/` is removed and the file will be named `absolute/path/file.ext` inside the archive.

Usually this is written to stderr when archiving files, please check that output, it may look like in this example:

```
# tar -cvf test.tar /etc/passwd
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/etc/passwd
# tar -tf test.tar
etc/passwd
```

Therefore please try running

```
tar --compare --file myArchive.tar.xz path/to/my/dir
```

leaving out the first character of the path if it is a `/`.